# Bug in HighchartsRenderer?

Tags: .net, highcharts

I use the DotNet package Highsoft.Highcharts to create code in backend. After this I use HighchartsRenderer.GetJsonOptions() to bring the code to frontend.

In exporting node the HighchartsRenderer is using no camel-case properties, e.g. "ContextButton" is used instead of "contextButton".

E.g.

```
public static Exporting CreateExporting(string downloadName, bool fitToPage)
{
    List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem
    {
        Text = "Chart als PNG runterladen",
        OnClick = "function(){ this.exportChart({type: 'image/png', filename: '" + downloadName + @"'}); }"
    });

    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem
    {
        Text = "Chart als JPEG runterladen",
        OnClick = @"function(){ this.exportChart({type: 'image/jpeg', filename: '" + downloadName + @"'}); }"
    });
    
    var exporting = new Exporting
    {
        Buttons = new ExportingButtons
        {
            ContextButton = new ExportingButtonsContextButton { MenuItems = menuItems.ToList() }
        },
        Enabled = downloadName != null,
        Url = $"/HighchartsExport.axd{(fitPdfToPage ? "?fitToPage=true" : "")}"
    };

    var theChart = new Highcharts();
    theChart.Exporting = exporting;

    var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(theChart);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(renderer.GetJsonOptions());
}
```

The result in JSON looks like this:

```
{"exporting":{"url":"/HighchartsExport.axd","buttons":{"ContextButton":{"_titleKey":"","Align":2,"ButtonSpacing":3.0,"ClassName":"highcharts-contextbutton","Enabled":true, ....
```

You see the "ContextButton" and all properties of it are UpperCamelCase.

Series, legend etc. are correct.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it? Is it a bug?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Could you tell me which version do you use?

Comment: I use the current version 8.1.1.1

Comment: It seems that it is related to `ExportingButtons` issue. I reported it to the Highcharts .NET creator, should be fixed in the next week.

Comment: Thank you. I found one more issue: In Legend property Padding is a string in C# but a number in JS.